DateTimeFormatter parsing is not working for month
I am trying to parse date using DateTimeFormatter . Below is my code.
String dateString = "JUN 2023"; 
                                        
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM yyyy");
        try {
            YearMonth startDateL = YearMonth.parse(dateString, formatter);
            System.out.println(startDateL); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error parsing YearMonth: " + e.getMessage());
        }

I am getting below error on running it
Error parsing YearMonth: Text 'JUN 2023' could not be parsed at index 0
I went through the documentation for DateTimeFormatter and not finding any mistakes. What is happening here

Jun seems to work - but not JUN.

maybe you want to use a DateTimeFormatterBuilder and its parseCaseInsensitive() method (and adding a Locale is (often) not an error)

this provides the builder sample.

Specify a Locale that matches the format of your input. And you may need to use DateTimeFormatterBuilder to add a requirement to ignore case. All-uppercase JUN does not match some locales, such as the US and UK.

You can use the DateTimeFormatterBuilder with parseCaseInsensitive to correct the casing as what will be recognized is Jun and not JUN
String dateString = "JUN 2023";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive() // Ignore case
        .appendPattern("MMM yyyy")
        .toFormatter();
try {
    YearMonth startDateL = YearMonth.parse(dateString, formatter);
    System.out.println(startDateL);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error parsing YearMonth: " + e.getMessage());
}

This way whatever case you use for month will be recognized

Just saw that this was already answered by @user85421 in the comments under the question. I'll leave this answer here though for other to pick out easily if they come across this question in the future.

it's OK for my part - I just do not want to answer (unless in some special cases)
